# Shouldn't we be able to edit comments as long as no one has commented after us?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've read other questions about why is there a 5 minute cutoff for editing comments but I don't think they address my issue. I don't think there should be a time limit on when you can edit comments. I understand that it often takes things out of context when you edit comments but I would rather have it editable until someone responds then the comments above would be locked. Does this make sense or are there disadvantages of doing so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It makes sense to me, but you can essentially do this already. Since you can always delete a comment, if yours is the last on a post, you can just copy it, hit delete, and then add a new comment and paste it then make the changes you want.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Editing it would make it a little easier, less clicks but same end result.

Comment: @evanb: I'd just change the order, _first_ add the new comment with the changes, only _then_ delete the old one. It can happen that another comment sneaks in before you submit the edited comment, and if you leave the old comment before submitting the edited one, then you still have the option to delete the edited comment instead of the old one.